# Missing Library - DurationFormatUtils - What do I download

Tags: java, groovy, apache-commons, duration

Someone gave me a class that requires DurationFormatUtils. Think this part of the Apache Commons. But I'm new to Java/Groovy and don't know what I should go download to solve this dependency.

Comment: What's the full package name of DurationFormatUtils (look at the import statements)?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that class is part of commons-lang, which is [available here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi)

You can see the dependencies [for v2.6 here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6), and [here for v3.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0) along with the required code to import the package using maven, ivy, buildr, or Groovy's `@Grab`